# Initializing variables that dynamically created inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init, ng-init

I need to create variables dynamically inside `ng-repeat` and initialize it using `ng-init`.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="r in ['first','second','third']" data-ng-init="{{'panel'+$index}}=true">
      {{'panel'+$index}} 
   </div>
```

The output of the above code is,

```
panel0
panel1
panel2
```

But I need the following output,

```
true
true
true
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qL2TXrgipR9RdVN2Vu0x?p=preview) is the plunker.

Comment: can you explain your problem in brief?

Comment: you can create input hidden field and the set the value !

Comment: You don't need to initialize variables inside an `ng-repeat`. The **view** is there only to render your **model**, not do any logic. This is not good practice at all. Create your custom variables in your controller, and then use `ng-repeat` to print them out, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your values as an array:

```
<div id="{{'panel'+$index}}" data-ng-repeat="r in ['first','second','third']" data-ng-init="t['panel'+$index]=true">
      {{t['panel'+$index]}} 
</div>
```